# Sudden Drop of Volatile GPU-Util Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I am running https://github.com/jadore801120/attention-is-all-you-need-pytorch this code that has implemented the paper [Attention-is-all-you-need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) with PyTorch with [Gigaword dataset](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2012T21), so the task is changed into text summarization from the original paper's intent, machine translation (dataset name is WST2016).

The dataset is much bigger in Gigaword comparing to WST2016, total size of training dataset is 3,800,000 and 29,056 respectively.

The problem is, when I train Gigaword, exactly when the graph trains the 31% of the entire data, it gets dramatically slows down, up to 30 times become slower linearly with GPU util become 0-15% from 99-100%.

I can't figure out why the training gets slow down exactly at 31% of a batch.

What would be the possible start point to debug this problem?

Comment: This can be any number of things. Memory limitations, dataset inconcistency (e.g. a sentence that is way too long due to faulty parsing), exploding gradients, etc. You can try: preprocessing the data and only keeping sentences that are between a given token range (e.g. 3-50), shuffling the data and see whether the same happens, monitoring GPU memory consumption.

Comment: @BramVanroy The github repo I referred already did the token range preprocessing and does the random shuffling. What can I doubt about then ?